# Is it possible to reuse a monad composition function if one of the monads is wrapped inside a monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Let's say I have function that composes two monad actions:

`co :: Monad m => m a -> m a -> m a`

You can think of `co` as a higher order function that describes how two monadic actions may cooperate with each other to complete a task.

But now I find that the first monadic action may be wrapped inside a monad transformer, while the second one is not:

`one :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t m a`

`two :: Monad m => m a`

But would like to compose them together still, so I need a function:

`co' :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t m a -> m a -> t m a`

So that the first `t m a` can cooperate with `m a` by just lifting all `m` primitives into the context `t`.

The trick here is to build `co` without really knowing the implementation of `m` or `t`. I feel like the answer is somewhere in the MFunctor package, and in fact asked a similar question yesterday. But cannot come up with anything good, any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `hoist` from the `mmorph` package.  `hoist` lets you modify the base monad of anything that implements `MFunctor` (which is most monad transformers):

```
hoist :: (MFunctor t) => (forall x . m x -> n x) -> t m r -> t n r
```

You can then use it for your problem like this:

```
co' tma ma = hoist (co ma) tma
```

Then you're done!

To understand why that works, let's go through the types step by step:

```
co :: (Monad m) => m a -> m a -> m a

ma :: (Monad m) => m a

co ma :: (Monad m) => m a -> m a

hoist (co ma) :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => t m a -> t m a

tma :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => t m a

hoist (co ma) tma :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => t m a
```

Note that `hoist` has certain laws it must satisfy that ensure that it does "the right thing" that you would expect:

```
hoist id = id

hoist (f . g) = hoist f . hoist g
```

These are just functor laws, guaranteeing that `hoist` behaves intuitively.

`hoist` is provided in the `Control.Monad.Morph` module of the `mmorph` package, which you can find [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph).  The bottom of the main module has [a tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mmorph/1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Morph.html#g:3) teaching how to use the package

Answer (score 2):

### Quick Definition

You need `t m` to have a monad instance for this to work.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans

co :: Monad m => m a -> m a -> m a
co = undefined

co' :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => t m a -> m a -> t m a
co' one two = lift . flip co two . return  =<< one
```

### Alternative view on the problem

Seeing the  definition of `lift` from `transformers` package should help you find the answer as you want something similar

```
lift . return = return
lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= (lift . f)
```

As you have `flip co one :: Monad m => m a -> m a` and you want to lift it to get a function of type `(MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => t m a -> t m a`. So following on the footsteps of lift

```
lift' :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m, Monad (t m)) => (m a -> m a) -> t m a -> t m a
lift' f tma = tma >>= (lift . f . return)
```

Now defining `co'` is trivial

```
co' one two = lift' (flip co two) one
```

### Problem

The above solutions just satisfy the type, but do they satisfy the semantics too?
To see the problem lets take a `co` function which always returns the second action without even looking at the first. Now the above `co'` will never be able to do that as it always runs the first action before deciding anything. So the side effect of first action will still occur in the `co'` even though they dont occur in `co`.

### Does the general solution exist?

I suppose not. Because what you want to actually implement that function generically, is a function like `t m a -> (m a -> m b) -> t m b`, where you need to get action `m a` out of `t m a` without actually running the side effects of `m a`.

So suppose `m` is `IO` monad and `t` is State transformer with some state and your `one` action actually launches a missile and depending on the success or failure of that modifies the `State`. Now what you want is to actually modify the state without launching the missiles. In general that is not possible.

If you know some information about `co` like which action is run first, then you can implement `co'` using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

The [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.2.1) package can be used to lift functions and control operations from a base monad into a monad transformer, even those functions that take callbacks.

The [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.1.0) package builds on monad-control and contains lifted versions of many common functions dealing with exceptions, concurrency... In particular, it has a [lifted version](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lifted-base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v%3afinally) of [finally](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v%3afinally)  from Control.Exception, whose signature is very similar to that of `co`.

Here are some links:

http://www.yesodweb.com/book/monad-control

http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2013/08/exceptions-and-monad-transformers